# wp get image editor returns wp error

Tags: php, wordpress, image

I'm using aq_resize class to resize images and save them, but inside aq_resize.php there's a wordpress function

```
($editor = wp_get_image_editor( $img_path ))
```

always returning Error (wp_error)...

Here's a part of the malfunctioning code:

```
$editor = wp_get_image_editor( $img_path );
if ( is_wp_error( $editor ) || is_wp_error( $editor->resize( $width, $height, $crop ) ) )
    return false;
    $resized_file = $editor->save();
```

Comment: Can you tell us the error?

Comment: It only returns "wp_error" instead of an instance of wp_image_editor

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot so I can see what happens?

Comment: is 'GD and/or ImageMagick libraries' are On, on your server !